# getting error while converting UTC time zone to IST on Redshift database

Tags: amazon-redshift

While executing the function pg_timezone_names() and pg_timezone_abbrevs() in Redshift database, I am getting the error "pg_timezone_names is giving error as Invalid character data was found.  This is most likely caused by stored data containing characters that are invalid for the character set the database was created in.  The most common example of this is storing 8bit data in a SQL_ASCII database." That is the reason convert_timezone() function is not working for me. I am using SQL workbench tool to execute the functions.

I am trying to change the data format from UTC to IST in Redshift DB

Comment: What is the issue with just using `convert_timezone`? `select convert_timezone('UTC', 'IST', '20080305 12:25:29');`

Comment: Thanks for response. Please find below output on my statement                                                        select convert_timezone('UTC', 'IST', '20230908 09:23');

output 
2023-09-08 11:23:00.0

select now();
2023-09-09 09:22:56.411997
comment :after 5 mins  i executed the now() and it is showing the same value as .2023-09-09 09:22:56. Once i will re-connect it will reflect the current time in IST format after that the time is static till next  reconnect.

Comment: select getdate();
out put :2023-09-09 03:54:07.0
comment : it seems UTC time zone


select  pg_timezone_names();
Output :An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select  pg_timezone_names()

Invalid character data was found.  This is most likely caused by stored data containing characters that are invalid for the character set the database was created in.  The most common example of this is storing 8bit data in a SQL_ASCII database.
1 statement failed.

Comment: select pg_timezone_abbrevs();
 An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select pg_timezone_abbrevs()

Invalid character data was found.  This is most likely caused by stored data containing characters that are invalid for the character set the database was created in.  The most common example of this is storing 8bit data in a SQL_ASCII database.
1 statement failed.